# Hadoop PIG can dump but not store

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a PIG script which can dump the result of a calculus, but can't store it.... how can we explain that ? What kind of mistake can I be doing ?

The error on which the store is breaking is a java out of memory error.
Why can we display but not write the result ? The output directory is deleted and do not exist during the run.

Comment: Could you please update the error log ?

Comment: java OutOfMemory Error : Java heap space

Comment: What storage func are you using? What's your heap space? Have you tried increasing your heap? DUMP and STORE have significantly different properties, so I'm not surprised at the failure.

Comment: I am not sure how to set the heap size :-s